# Flutter image upload from camera unable to send data to server in android mobile

Tags: flutter, file-upload, image-upload, imagepicker

Flutter image upload from camera unable to send data to server in android mobile,

Using Flutter image_picker to upload image using camera or gallery option I can open and image build in UI.

When send to server gallery image is working fine, but camera option image not sending, any thing to change or solutions,

Thanks in advance

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';    

void main(){
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  XFile? _image; 
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  var imageData;
  var filename;
  Future<void> _openImagePicker() async {
    final XFile? pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    imageData = await pickedFile!.readAsBytes();
    setState(() {
      _image = pickedFile;      
    });
    filename = pickedFile.name;
  }

  Future<void> _openImageCameraPicker() async {
    final XFile? photo = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    imageData = await photo!.readAsBytes();
    setState(() {
      _image = photo;
    });
    filename = photo.name;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("image upload")),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _openImagePicker();              
            },
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.photo,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 28.0,
            ),
          ),          
          const SizedBox(height: 30.0),          
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _openImageCameraPicker();              
            },
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.camera,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 28.0,
            ),
          ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: _image != null ? (kIsWeb)
              ? Image.network(_image!.path,  fit: BoxFit.cover)
              : Image.file(File(_image!.path), fit: BoxFit.cover) : const Text('No Image'),
         ),
         ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            uploadImage();
          },
          child: const Text("Upload", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
         Text(imageData.toString()),
      ]),
    )
    );
  }
  Future uploadImage() async {
   Map<String,String> headers = {
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      };
      Map data = {
      'file' : (filename!=null) ? base64Encode(imageData) : '',
      'filename': (filename!=null) ? filename : ''
    };
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1/api/upload-image'),  body: jsonEncode(data), headers: headers);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      //succss      
    } else {
      // error
    }     
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error in the case camera?

Comment: In mobile camera captured photo and show in UI fine,  but when I hit to upload button it not send to server, how to get error log in mobile, Note I'm not using any emulator because my system space. in this above code ` imageData = await pickedFile!.readAsBytes();` gallery file upload it getting byte data when echo a sting in UI, but using camera `imageData  = await photo!.readAsBytes();`  but not seen any byte string

Comment: I have same issue, can any one have solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Brother if you don't send image from `camera` or `gallery` so probably you can send that you take ss image
you have to give `size(max height and max width )` in `image picker`.

```
final  image =  await  _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera,maxHeight: 200, maxWidth: 200);
```

Comment: it will solve the issue, but why it's happening, can you please explain a little bit !!!

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you not give maxHeight and maxWidth to getImage() method in Image Picker. Just do as below

```
await ImagePicker().getImage(source: source, maxHeight: 2200, maxWidth: 2200)
```